# Read characters within brackets ()

Tags: c#, javascript

I have written a c# code to read string values within brackets "()"

```
 string s = "Hello (World) This is (Working)";
            int i = 0;
            while ((i = s.IndexOf('(', i)) != -1)
            {
                int stop = s.Substring(i+1).IndexOf(')');
                string output = s.Substring(i + 1, stop);
                Console.WriteLine(output);

                i++;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

with this code I get

> World Working

I want to implement this in JavaScript So I tried this

```
function myFunction()
{
var s = "Hello (World) This is (Working)";
            var i = 0;
            while ((i = s.indexOf('(', i)) != -1)
            {
                var stop = s.substring(i+1).indexOf(')');
                var output = s.substring(i+1, stop);
                document.write(output);
                i++;
            }
}
```

but It has different output

> ss (

I am not good at javaScript, Please help me find a solution in this method I dont want to use regex

Comment: Why don't you want to use regex? That's the logical way to do it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite similar names, these aren't actually using equivalent methods (note the 2nd arguments):

- C# -- [`Substring(int index, int length)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)
- JS -- [`substring(int indexA, int indexB)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Try `substr` instead for the JavaScript -- [`substr(int index, int length)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
function myFunction()
{
    var s = "Hello (World) This is (Working)";
    var i = 0;
    while ((i = s.indexOf('(', i)) != -1)
    {
        var stop = s.substr(i+1).indexOf(')');
        var output = s.substr(i+1, stop);
        document.write(output);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works good if we use alert(output); but it displays only World when we use document.write(output); anyway thanks this really helped

Comment: @Frank Try `console.log` with a [built-in or plugin debugger](http://www.browserstack.com/debugging-tools). http://jsfiddle.net/f7S3J/

Answer (score 1):

For simple control logics, it is better to use converters.

You can try [SharpKit](http://sharpkit.net/) to convert c# code to javascript. It is free to use for small or open source projects.

Comment: function MyMethod()
{
    var s="Hello (World) This is (Working)";
    var i=0;
    while((i = s.indexOf('(',i)) != -1)
    {
        var stop=s.substr(i + 1).indexOf(')');
        var output=s.substr(i + 1,stop);
        alert(output);
        i++;
    }
};
wow Got exactly What I need Thanks

Comment: You can update your findings (whether question is resolved or still some gaps are there) in the Question itself. Comments section is not suited for code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's not the best code but it will do what you ask:

```
var thestring = 'Hello (World) This is (Working)';
var words = thestring.match(/(\([A-Za-z]+\))/g);
words = words.join('-').replace(/[\(\)]/g,'').split('-');
```

**UPDATE**.
I didn't read the parte "I don't want to use regex" but maybe you should. I don't know much regex but I do what I can and try to learn more about that... world. :|

Comment: yes I accept that, I will learn regex and I will try to solve the same in regex thanx

Answer (score 0):

That's what do you want?

```
function myFunction() {
    var s = "Hello (World) This is (Working)";
    var i = 0;
    var outputs = [];
    while ((i = s.indexOf('(', i)) != -1) {
        var stop = s.indexOf(')', i);
        outputs.push(s.slice(i + 1, stop));
        i++;
    }
    document.write(outputs.join(' ')); // World Working
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t6PBp/)**

Answer (score 0):

I find for loops much more readable. Here is my take.

```
function myFunction() {
    var s = "Hello (World) This is (Working)";
    var output = false;
    for (i = 0; i <= s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i] == ')') {
            if (i != s.length) document.write(' ');
            output = false
        }
        if (output) document.write(s[i]);
        if (s[i] == '(') output = true;
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H6YBQ/)